# How do I print which tables a value is in when using a LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, left-join

How do I print which tables a value is in when using a LEFT JOIN?

I am trying to get a get a LEFT JOIN table like so:

| id | name | present in |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Table 1 |
| 2 | Jane | Table 1, Table 2 |
| 3 | Emily | Table 2 |
| 4 | George |  |

Source tables:

Master:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Jane |
| 3 | Emily |
| 4 | George |

Table 1:

| id | age |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 24 |

Table 2:

| id | age |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 24 |
| 3 | 36 |

I am trying set the values in an array variable but the query errors out.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask about 1 bad definition/query/function with the obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & ideally a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT master.*,
       CONCAT_WS(',', 
                 CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
                                   FROM table1 
                                   WHERE master.id = table1.id)
                      THEN 'Table 1'
                      END, 
                 CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
                                   FROM table2
                                   WHERE master.id = table2.id)
                      THEN 'Table 2'
                      END) `present in`
FROM master
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I was trying more complex solutions like assigning to an array and concatenation